How to unit-test a program using fork/exec with libcheck?
I'm trying to test a program, that forks and execs with libcheck (https://github.com/libcheck/check).
When I run the program normally it is able to create the subprocess waits a bit and then kills it with SIGTERM without problems. However, if I'm doing the same in a test, the test fails with Received signal 15 (Terminated). It seams like the test process gets killed instead.
When running the test with strace, I don't even see the kill being executed.
When running the test with strace and CK_FORK=no, the kill is executed, but the program is aborted during the wait.
In addition I don't really now how to debug it properly.
test.c:
#include <check.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <paths.h>
#include <unistd.h>

START_TEST(test)
{
    int process;

    /* prevent duplicate output from the child process */
    if (0 != fflush (NULL)) abort ();

    process = fork ();
    if (0 > process) abort ();

    /* child process */
    if (0 == process)
    {
        int null_fd;

        /* reset signals */
        if (SIG_ERR == signal (SIGTERM, SIG_DFL))
        {
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        /* Replace stderr with /dev/null, because SoX will
         * spam the output with current status data. */
        null_fd = open (_PATH_DEVNULL, O_WRONLY);
        if (0 > null_fd)
        {
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (0 > dup2 (null_fd, STDERR_FILENO))
        {
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (0 > close (null_fd))
        {
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        execlp ("/usr/bin/play", (char *) NULL);

        /* execvp failed */
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    printf("kill: %d\n", process);

    if (0 > kill (process, SIGTERM)) abort ();

    if (0 > waitpid (process, NULL, 0)) abort ();
}
END_TEST


Suite * suite (void)
{
    Suite *s;
    TCase *tc_core;

    s = suite_create ("Test");

    /* Core test case */
    tc_core = tcase_create ("Test");

    tcase_add_test (tc_core, test);
    suite_add_tcase (s, tc_core);

    return s;
}

int main (void)
{
    int number_failed;
    Suite *s;
    SRunner *sr;

    s = suite ();
    sr = srunner_create (s);

    srunner_run_all (sr, CK_NORMAL);
    number_failed = srunner_ntests_failed (sr);
    srunner_free (sr);

    return (number_failed == 0) ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
}

I've removed the error checking from the code.
This can be compiled using gcc test.c -lcheck_pic -pthread -lrt -lm -lsubunit

executing it:

$ ./a.out 
Running suite(s): Test
kill: 7047
0%: Checks: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1
test.c:11:E:Test:test:0: (after this point) Received signal 15 (Terminated)


with strace

$ strace -fe trace=%process,%signal ./a.out 
execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], 0x7ffc8a157ef0 /* 47 vars */) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0x7fd6fd8c9690, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7fd6fd8d6140}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0x7fd6fd8c9730, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7fd6fd8d6140}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {sa_handler=0x5638b7e93b50, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fd6fd8d6140}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x5638b7e93b50, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fd6fd8d6140}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=0x5638b7e93b50, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fd6fd8d6140}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
Running suite(s): Test
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fd6fd5a0550) = 6995
strace: Process 6995 attached
[pid  6994] wait4(6995,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  6995] clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fd6fd5a0550) = 6996
strace: Process 6996 attached
kill: 6996
[pid  6995] kill(6996, SIGTERM)         = 0
[pid  6996] --- SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=6995, si_uid=1001} ---
[pid  6995] wait4(6996,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  6996] rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fd6fd8d6140}, NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  6996] kill(-6995, SIGTERM)        = 0
[pid  6995] <... wait4 resumed>NULL, 0, NULL) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
[pid  6995] --- SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=6996, si_uid=1001} ---
[pid  6996] kill(-6995, SIGTERM)        = 0
[pid  6996] rt_sigreturn({mask=[]} <unfinished ...>
[pid  6995] rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fd6fd8d6140},  <unfinished ...>
[pid  6996] <... rt_sigreturn resumed>) = 140561350264128
[pid  6996] --- SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=6996, si_uid=1001} ---
[pid  6995] <... rt_sigaction resumed>NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  6995] kill(-6995, SIGTERM)        = 0
[pid  6995] kill(-6995, SIGTERM)        = 0
[pid  6995] rt_sigreturn({mask=[]} <unfinished ...>
[pid  6996] +++ killed by SIGTERM +++
[pid  6995] <... rt_sigreturn resumed>) = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
[pid  6995] --- SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=6996, si_uid=1001} ---
[pid  6995] +++ killed by SIGTERM +++
<... wait4 resumed>[{WIFSIGNALED(s) && WTERMSIG(s) == SIGTERM}], 0, NULL) = 6995
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_KILLED, si_pid=6995, si_uid=1001, si_status=SIGTERM, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
kill(-6995, SIGKILL)                    = -1 ESRCH (No such process)
0%: Checks: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1
test.c:11:E:Test:test:0: (after this point) Received signal 15 (Terminated)
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fd6fd8d6140}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fd6fd8d6140}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fd6fd8d6140}, NULL, 8) = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++

Strangely, once in a while it actually works, which seams to be correlated to the current system load. If my CPU is nearly idle, the success rate is around 50%, when my CPU is under load, then it nearly always fails.
When it succeeds, it looks like this:

executing:

Running suite(s): Test
kill: 7074
100%: Checks: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0


with strace

execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], 0x7ffd0a5de0d0 /* 47 vars */) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0x7f216e4fa690, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7f216e507140}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0x7f216e4fa730, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7f216e507140}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {sa_handler=0x55988f29db50, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f216e507140}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x55988f29db50, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f216e507140}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=0x55988f29db50, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f216e507140}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
Running suite(s): Test
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f216e31f450) = 137654
wait4(137654, strace: Process 137654 attached
 <unfinished ...>
[pid 137654] clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f216e31f450) = 137655
strace: Process 137655 attached
kill: 137655
[pid 137655] rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[TERM], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f216e358d60}, {sa_handler=0x55988f29db50, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f216e507140}, 8) = 0
[pid 137654] kill(137655, SIGTERM)      = 0
[pid 137655] --- SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=137654, si_uid=1001} ---
[pid 137654] wait4(137655,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 137655] +++ killed by SIGTERM +++
[pid 137654] <... wait4 resumed>NULL, 0, NULL) = 137655
[pid 137654] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_KILLED, si_pid=137655, si_uid=1001, si_status=SIGTERM, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
[pid 137654] exit_group(0)              = ?
[pid 137654] +++ exited with 0 +++
<... wait4 resumed>[{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 137654
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=137654, si_uid=1001, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
kill(-137654, SIGKILL)                  = -1 ESRCH (No such process)
100%: Checks: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f216e507140}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f216e507140}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f216e507140}, NULL, 8) = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++


Please [edit] your question and show a [mre] instead of code snippets. We should be able to run your program(s) and reproduce the problem.

What does strace -fe trace=%process,%signal ... show?

@pilcrow I added it into the question. The "kill: " is coming from the printf. Could it be, that my process is killed by SIGCHLD ?

Your trace does not match your narrative.  It shows everything working, and indeed shows 100%: Checks: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0.  Please show us how to reproduce the problem, and the exact output you get at the terminal.

I see. I first added another output and then rerun again and then it looked shorter, so I uploaded that, but that seams to miss the bug. So trying it again, it seams like it once every while it actually works, but most times it doesn't, which sounds like a race condition...

libcheck installs a SIGTERM handler which kills the whole process group.  This handler is inherited by the grandchild process, which is killed before it can exec the program you actually want to run.
Your forking run has three processes:
A: a.out
    \
B:   (forked test suite)
      \
C:     (forked process in test case)

Process C inherits the signal disposition installed by libcheck and, again, catches the SIGTERM and kills the whole process group before it can exec.
Delaying the kill until the exec has succeeded resolves this problem, since execve will reset the user-supplied signal disposition to SIG_DFL, and thus the granchild will die by SIGTERM.  Stackoverflow has a number of questions about delaying a parent until a child completes an exec if you are looking for techniques.

If I add a sleep, the exec actually happens, but now it fails with a different error, namely SIGTTOU. Should I add it to the existing question or create a new, although I don't know how to ask differently?

@Caulder, new question, please. That’s probably again libcheck modifying process attributes and your “grandchild” program writing to a terminal — but you might solve the problem in researching how to ask it here as a separate question.

I solved it partially now. libcheck is running the test in the background, but process C is trying to set the terminal settings, which raises SIGTTOU. I now just ignore SIGTTOU. Do you think it makes sense to look for a different solution or is this the intended behaviour?
